# EditText in Alert Dialog Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a method to create an Alert Dialog in a fragment

```
private void alertDialog() {
final EditText editTextField = new EditText(this.getContext());
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder()
    .setTitle("Title")
    .setMessage("Message")
    .setView(editTextField)
    .setPositiveButton("OK", this)
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
    .create();
dialog.show();
}
```

Then I have implemented the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i){
 switch(i){
    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
        String name = String.valueOf(editTextField.getText());
        break;
    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
        break;
   }
 }
```

However the `editTextField` in `onClick` method doesn't able to reference to the Alert Dialog. Is there anyway to solve this? Or the only way is to create a layout with edit text and `setView` into alert dialog builder?

Comment: You  mean when `editText` is clicked, nothing happen ?

Comment: No, the editTextField.getText() cannot resolve. @JohnJoe

Comment: @EricLow you are declaring the edittext as local variable in alertdialog.and you cannot access that variable outside that method

Comment: `final EditText editTextField` is local, therefore exists only inside `alertDialog()` method. Therefore you can't access it outside of it. You need to declare it global

Comment: @Vladyslav Matviienko , yes I know, but if declare as global, I can't do the setView. The error shows NullPointerException: attempt to invoke virtual methoed 'android.content.res.Resouces.

Comment: that means you did something wrong while declaring it global. You don't need to **assign** it, only declare

Comment: Sorry for late reply. You're right, I assigned it with something. Got it now, thank you so much. @VladyslavMatviienko

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason you are not able to access editTextField is because of it is declared as **local variable in alertDialog()** method.

If in case you want to keep that variable as local ,you need to set the listener method directly in that method as i show below.

```
private EditText = new EditText(this);
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Title")
                .setMessage("Message")
                .setView(inputEditTextField)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        String editTextInput = inputEditTextField.getText().toString();
                        Log.d("onclick","editext value is: "+ editTextInput);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .create();
dialog.show();
```

Else you can replace  this line from alertDialog() method with this below line

```
editTextField = new EditText(this.getContext());
```

you need add this line above onCreate method

```
EditTextField editTextField;
```

Comment: I declared it wrongly, your answer helps too. Thank you so much.

Comment: inputEditTextField not found

Comment: replace inputEditTextField to editTextField

Answer (score 9):

The same on Kotlin:

```
    val inputEditTextField = EditText(requireActivity())
    val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
        .setTitle("Title")
        .setMessage("Message")
        .setView(inputEditTextField)
        .setPositiveButton("OK") { _, _ ->
                val editTextInput = inputEditTextField .text.toString()
                Timber.d("editext value is: $editTextInput")
        }
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
        .create()
    dialog.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

use thi

```
    EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Create group")
            .setMessage("Enter group name")
            .setView(editText)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", (dialogInterface, i) -> {
                String editTextInput = editText.getText().toString();
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .create();
    dialog.show();
```